# Two table select query using there id, id have same value but need all data combine

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table table 1 and table 2.

Table 1 have four field.

1. cId
2. fname
3. lName
4. userId

Table 2 have four field.

1. qId
2. CKId
3. category
4. desc

In both table cId and cKID is common, they have customer Id.

I need to combine both table data and orderby fname.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called inner join and is given in the mysql manual.

```
SELECT cid,fname,iname, userid, qid, category, `desc` 
 FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.cid = table2.ckid order by fname
```

you don't want to use 'desc' as a column name because it is confusion. DESC means descending in a query clause. So if possible try to rename that field in your table

Comment: Thanks for answering